# Make Milestone fields available in Case List Views so cases can be prioritized

Tags: casemilestone

Anyone know if this is possible yet?

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000i6KFAAY

Comment: there are different ways it can be achieved. What is your specific requirement?

Comment: Hi Santanu. We need to add the target resolution date to views. Thanks

Comment: Can you check my answer if that solves your purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-box Milestone's field has not been exposed by Salesforce to add it to Listview.

**Workaround**

Create a Datetime field on Case object and try to update that field from trigger or process builder with a combination of flow, querying Milestones record.

And finally add this field to ListView.